# How to process multiple gRPC futures?

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, future, grpc

I have several gRPC stubs. I want to call them asynchronously and then combine their results (with small postprocessing) into one. With plain Python futures I could use `concurrent.futures.as_completed` or `concurrent.futures.wait` but gRPC futures [does not support this functions](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18611).

How can I invoke gRPC stubs in parallel and efficiently combine their results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke each call as `stub.SayHello.futures(HelloRequest(name="world"))` to achieve parallelism. However, to combine their result, there isn't a more convenient way than iterate through the list of rpcs and wait on each one of them.

If you found this feature useful, please ping the GitHub issue, and add your use case ;)